# Force a component property to be an h2

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to define a props interface for a component using Typescript which requires the value passed for that property to be an instance of `<h2>`-`<h6>` (not an `<h1>` though).

I initially tried to do this, but it doesn't force the typing like I want:

```
type HeaderType = 'h2' | 'h3' | 'h4' | 'h5' | 'h6';

interface OwnProps {
    title?: React.ReactElement<HeaderType>;
}
```

This doesn't seem to work either (and I believe it would include h1 which I don't want):

```
interface OwnProps {
    title?: React.ReactElement<HTMLHeadingElement>;
}
```

I understand I could throw a run-time error after inspecting the input in the component, but is there any way to restrict the tag type for a prop in React?

Comment: Sadly, I don't think you can. You can easily make it a runtime error (as I'm sure you know), but having played around with the things I thought would work, I don't think you can make it a type error. **But**, I'm still only a journeyman at TypeScript, hopefully someone better at it than I can do it. (I can think of alternatives, but nothing that literally does what you've said you want.)

Comment: (For instance, I thought [something like this](https://tsplay.dev/wE5bOw) would work, but...no.)

Comment: just to make sure I'm reading this right, you want title to be _instances_ of the React `h2` through `h6` components?

Comment: I can't think of a way to do this since h1 is the same type as h2. Of course you could make a component like <NotTooBigHeader v={2|3|4|5|6}> that adds the header tag with your restrictions.

Comment: @im1dermike would rewriting your component be an option? E.g. not passing a fully formed React component as title, but instead using two props `title: string` and `heading: "h2" | "h3" | ...` and then have the component you're building make the actual heading as part of its render() call.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans That was what I originally had done, but was like "This interface sucks. Can Typescript help?" :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a tricky problem, primarily around trying to get a good developer experience.

My first thought was `H2` to `H6` *components*, since we can then restrict `title` the way you say you want to (which I don't think we can with `"h2"` to `"h6"` tags). That seemed really promising until the dev experience, which turned out to be really disappointing. (I've included it below just for reference.)

My second thought was that `title` could be a `{tag: HeaderType; text: string;}` object type, but that's no better from a devex point of view than what you had and what [Mike suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71279775/157247).

But React gets really good use of *tuples*, and the devex of making `title` a tuple seems decent:

[image: VS Code showing auto-complete suggestions for "h2" through "h6" for first element of tuple]

Here's the implementation:

```typescript
type HeaderType = "h2" | "h3" | "h4" | "h5" | "h6";
type Title = [tag: HeaderType, text: ReactNode];

interface OwnProps {
    title?: Title;
}
```

Using it on a `Section` component:

```typescript
const Section = ({ title, children }: PropsWithChildren<OwnProps>) => {
    return <section>
        {title && createElement(title[0], { children: title[1] })}
        {children}
    </section>;
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDec1SoxICiANkiEgHZZwAKUEYAzgOrAwAWAwl8GQAmhatmToYAOQiCkcAL5wAZkxBwARIQnqA3AFgAUIZgBPMHIASqWVAAqZuQF4NXAEzq4AHxcBmD9-UuABZ-FwBWUMCANl1jBzhbTgo4ZwBtGBQAcwAuOCsUG3tzbGIADxhc8QxpWQBdfSMDYFokKCV0OQB5AHdqRmYWXEM4EbgYJKQAflzEmAoG+UNDNAhqFngAZSQMYFWUuAAKPHG5pGw0fiERBVz+1g5uPgFhGgAeHr6mVgA+AEoU75DAyjOCEGAAVyg1DgrxY23Gq2+wxBoxwJ2SADIMfgtMRyJQaDADuikKkAAy1bB4C7PES5EmpACMtQUv0WwJRIxwNKuNHZINeAHo4TtEQsGstVus4CRSihwMlnAd-o5AThkSMwZDoa8tqLoSTHDhUoF3Nh1ABJWhMQTg-XqWryb5Wsb8QYihHQ7pIAB0fqFes933FQA)

---

The component solution was this:

If it were *components* we were trying to do this for, we could readily do it as:

```typescript
type HeaderType =
    | React.ReactElement<typeof ThisComponent>
    | React.ReactElement<typeof ThatComponent>
    | React.ReactElement<typeof TheOtherComponent>
    // ...
```

So we could make `H2` through `H6` components. We *could* do it by just repeating ourselves:

```typescript
const H2 = (props: ComponentProps<"h2">) => <h2 {...props}/>;
const H3 = (props: ComponentProps<"h3">) => <h3 {...props}/>;
// ....
```

...but even though there are only five `h2`...`h6` tags, maybe we'll want to do this for *other* tags as well. So maybe a utility function:

```typescript
const componentFor = <Tag extends keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements>(tag: Tag) =>
    (props: ComponentProps<Tag>) => React.createElement(tag, props);
```

Then defining these (and perhaps others some other time) is quite simple:

```typescript
const H2 = componentFor("h2");
const H3 = componentFor("h3");
const H4 = componentFor("h4");
const H5 = componentFor("h5");
const H6 = componentFor("h6");
```

Then our `HeaderType` is:

```typescript
type HeaderType =
    | React.ReactElement<typeof H2>
    | React.ReactElement<typeof H3>
    | React.ReactElement<typeof H4>
    | React.ReactElement<typeof H5>
    | React.ReactElement<typeof H6>;
```

But the devex isn't that great, the auto-complete just shows all components in scope:

[image: VS Code showing auto-complete suggestions for all components in scope]

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecDCE4EAdkiTAApQRgDOcAvnAGY0hwBEUqGnA3AFgAUCLSk68ccTIUAYtDgBeOAB4AKigDmcJAA8Y5ACYMA1kgCeEFnABSAZQAaAOgCSFKMBJ1gaAKIANkgg5DB0AHwAFDDaAFxwmloAlMrhInAZcJFgNPTxhDKh1LR0GtrhKUrhiLwwzmg8KIaBwaHR2tg5JUlCosLi3vAAEgBMynDSkLIwClCRnAAWI5w9YhLDAMzjk6Shs-MLGyu9A5JwQwAs20RTe9AHF8drg+cArNeF8veLr0-96+cAGwfW5fOaLQF-EQwCxgJDnVBGJBQdSw+FKdKZAA+NXQdWQeJaIQoqhhcOs5xGaWEmTgOIJGGcDJgRNCpLRFKGG2ptPptSZtVZJLJSE5Fx52NxjOZQpg7PJNiGrwlGT5eIFhKCxLlIs5gPCvREXkMUBY6HhAHkAO4kYr0XCYjIwYAwIIAfniQ0RyNRcN6jBEzzO9iQGGApHGkTwztdSGwaAWwACRh4JCY8WZzjtdAA6i6FvhE8nU6prbbchFKtUcI64DwYABXKBp1R0UPO0gq2m4GNBAM07sZHAJpMp8j92mqAD0bbDnf9hv+Lz8ehQ4CCkarDoHGXrTZbIbnad7SCUOFUo3C7hgNCMDaP08vjCvx8TDFnHbTVqQzl-08Pn4GiIjD8EAA)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to address this is probably to go back to a component where you tell it what heading text to use through the `title` property, with a separate property for "which level of heading this is", e.g.

```
import * as React from "react";

interface CardProps {
  title: string;
  level: 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6;
}

const Card = function(props: CardProps) {
  const heading = React.createElement(`h${props.level}`, {
    children: props.title,
  });

  return (
    <div className="some-card-class">
      {heading}
      ...etc...
    </div>
  );
};

// TS error:
const card1 = <Card title="this is the title" level={1} />;

// Not a TS error:
const card2 = <Card title="this is the title" level={2} />;
```

(Although of course in this example, code questions should be raised because I wrote this as a card, and cards shouldn't have a heading "level"; semantically, heading depth is relative to the document they're in, and a card is essentially its own (embedded) mini-document on a page, so you'd actually want to only use `h1`, making the need for a level property moot =)

Comment: This is exactly the way I had programmed it before wanting to see if the DX could be improved by Typescript

Comment: hahaha well alright then. What is the actual thing you're trying to type up, though? Because it might be worth updating the question with, in case there's some "best practice" way to do what you're trying to do, specifically, rather than "conceptually".