# How to enforce a strongly typed ReactElement as a React children?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Hi I'm trying to set up a strongly typed `children` prop in React. I want the `children` to be an element created by specific component - for example some i18n `Message` component.

I want to achieve something like this:

```
type HeadlineProps = {
  children: ReactElement<ComponentProps<typeof Message>>
}

...

<Headline>
  <Message id="test" text="Test" />   // <-- correct
<Headline>

<Headline>
  <span>Test</span>   // <-- TS Error
<Headline>

<Headline>
  <Button />   // <-- TS Error
<Headline>
```

I've tried

- type children `ReactElement<ComponentProps<typeof Message>>`
- or even simpler `ReactElement<{ id: string; text: string }>`
- explicitly set return type of `Message` component to `ReactElement<MessageProps>` (it was `JSX.Element` implicitly)

None of these would trigger any TS errors. I'm able to put any `children` as long as it's an `Element` type.

Is there a way for a component to only accept certain elements as its `children`?

Comment: Sadly, you can't. Ignore the upvoted answer on the linked question, I'll post a correct answer there.

Comment: In your specific case, I would make `Headline` not accept children at all, and instead accept a prop: https://tsplay.dev/WJqBrm

Comment: Slightly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71269888/force-a-component-property-to-be-an-h2 There the distinction was a string literal union rather than a component function, but...

Comment: That's what I thought so :/ I see that components are strictly typed in React, but when it comes to Elements, it's very loose. Anyway, thanks for the example and explanation. I'll do it the way with passing props.